# requestAnimationFrame and key listeners not working together:

Tags: javascript, game-engine, requestanimationframe

I'm attempting to write a custom game engine and I've written a function to check if a key is being pressed. Here's how it's being used:

```
Ball.prototype.update = function(){
    keys.onKey("space", function(){
        //Key pressed
    });
}
```

I call `update` on the `Ball` instance using `requestAnimationFrame()`. The problem is that the callback is being called more than once when I press the spacebar only one time. I believe the problem is being caused by requestAnimationFrame being called faster than they keylisteners leading to the multiple keystrokes.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxL3hw3c/) to illustrate the situation. Notice how the "space pressed" counter raises in 2s, 3s, or 4s, instead of 1s.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the deliberate intention of your code. The `.processKeyDown()` method fire once and remembers the key that is pressed then the `.onKey()` method (which I consider misnamed thus misleads you to believe it should fire only once) simply checks what that key was. To avoid the confusion I think you should rename `isKeyDown` to `isKeyCodeDown` and rename `onKey` to `isKeyDown`.

Comment: If you want the event to only be fired on key down then you need to do it somewhere in the `.processKeyDown()` function.

Comment: @slebetman thanks for the suggestions. The reason I didn't do everything in `.processKeyDown()` was so that I could evaluate which key was pressed, how can I still implement my `.onKey("space")` pattern this way - if it's even possible ?

Comment: Are you really **sure** you want `onKey` to fire only once? Because it means that `.onKey()` will no longer be able to "evaluate which key was pressed" which would defeat your design. It would mean that pressing the arrow keys would move your character only once instead of continuously (which I presume is the reason you designed it that way). It seems like what you really want are two different functionality depending on use case: evaluate which key is being pressed AND detect keypress event

Comment: @slebetman sorry for being unclear, I actually do want the player to move if the key is being held, ie: it's being pressed more than one time. However, what I don't understand is that if I press the spacebar once, it should only count as one time right? And if I hold it it should count as multiple times, therefore firing the event that many times. However now, if I press it once it fires more than once.

Comment: You did not press the spacebar once. You're not fast enough. requestAnimationFrame runs at 60Hz which is far faster than human reaction times. You can probably build a robot to do it if you want. For reference, radio controlled planes and helicopters are incredibly sensitive requiring a pilot to correct deviations very quickly to avoid a crash (or worse, killing someone). Yet radio control systems (even multirotors) send commands at a rate of 20Hz. At 20Hz a human feels the system as real-time. Your loop is running 3 times faster than real-time.

Comment: Basically, your loop is working correctly, don't worry about it.

Comment: An alternative is to remove all the `onKey` and `isKeyDown` parts of your code and handle keypresses directly in `processKeyDown` then depend on the keyboard repeat functionality to move your character multiple times. I have a strong feeling that this is not what you want however because the result is jerky.

Comment: @slebetman thanks again for all the help. The only reason I'm worrying about it is because the action happens more than once when it should only happen once. I'm curious to see how other game engines interpret keyboard signals. Like, pressing the spacebar once shoots once, etc. I'll try to integrate this into `processKeyDown`,.